# Django- how to create relational objects with depth set in serializer?

Tags: python, django, rest

There are two tables, `user` and `phone`; phone has foreign key `phone_user` linked to user table. With **depth** set in the serializer, we can get phone information from user. Thus 'Get' phone returns full data  of a phone instead a phone id.

The question is how to create a new phone linked with an existing user?  This question is identical to **creating nested objects**. I tried to send json with full user data but failed. Error says "`phone_user cannot be null`".  User has been explicitly added in Phone, why it says user is null?

Please let me now how to take care of this.

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Phone
        depth=1

class PhoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Phone.objects.all()
    serializer_class=PhoneSerializer

user=requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/users/1/")
phone=dict()
phone['phone_user']=user
json_str=json.dumps(phone)

// returns 500 error code
request.post("http://127.0.0.1/phones/", data=json_str, headers=...)
```

Django also says *"Django cannot create nested objects, and you can use self-defined create or set read_only=True*".

Answer (score 1):

Since your serializer has its depth set to 1, you need to deserialize using just the ID of the user. So, instead of

`phone['phone_user']=user`

you should instead use

`phone['phone_user']=user['id']`

That is assuming your user object returned has an id field, though.